# Unable to access event object properties in Esper in Update Listener Method

Tags: java, events, listener, esper

I am sending some events to update listener method in Esper and i am receiving the object but **update()** method wraps it into some Hashmap. I am unable to retrieve the object from there.

```
public static class CEPListener implements UpdateListener {
     public void update(EventBean[] newData, EventBean[] oldData) {
            // put some condition here before sending to crowd.......
            System.out.println("Event received: "
                                + newData[0].getUnderlying());
             System.out.println("Sending event to crowd.........");     
        }
    }
```

In the above function I can get my desired object inside **newData** but it is wrapped in some map and I am unable to find the method to retrieve my object from it. In the below screen **newData[0].getUnderlying()** has various attributes and I require the value object under red rectangle which I am unable to access as per [object methods](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.4.0/esper-javadoc/com/espertech/esper/client/EventBean.html#get(java.lang.String)). Will be thankful for the help. [image: Attributes of newData[0].getUnderlying()]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have got the answer.

```
             for (EventBean eb : newData) {
                if (eb instanceof MapEventBean) {
                    //MapEvent event = null;
                    if (eb.getUnderlying() instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                        Map<?, ?> alert = (Map<?, ?>) eb.getUnderlying();
                        for (Entry<?, ?> entry : alert.entrySet())
                        {
                            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
                        }


                    }
```